# What is the best practice for git with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, git

We have a SQL Server database with around 1000 stored procedures. We never used git to keep that code (okay okay I know).

Now, when we have three db developers instead of one, we want to start doing all correct, so we want all code to be kept in git.

We kindly ask for advise on how this should be done.

As far we see two strategies:

**1.** Have one single file which keeps all procedures

It would look like

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('my_procedure'))
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE my_procedure
END

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].my_procedure ...
```

So running this huge file would drop ALL procedures on release and create them again.

**2.** Have a single file on each stored procedure, which does the same as above

PROS/CONS

First approach lets us have single project code, where you can always see when and why and by whom any procedure was changed. So all developers change that single file and merge on conflict. But this approach would kill all PLANS on date of release, so that probably would slow down database (?)

Second approach lets us change single procedure without killing all others. But in that approach we will have 1000+ files and have know idea how to run on date of release only changed ones.

Thanks for advise.

Comment: Old version SQL? Because your syntax is so... instead DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But in that approach we will have 1000+ files and have know idea how to run on date of
> release only changed ones.

Yeah, and even imagine you have table changes. What you do then? Drop and recreate all tables?

The standard approach - in various forms - is to have (manually or automatically generated) change scripts. We do that - check them into Git with folders and running numbers, and have a sync mechanism that basically checks which have not run and runs them in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [SQL Server Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017).  It will facilitate both the git repo interaction, and the deployments.

The approach it takes is to use a file per procedure, and on deployment compare the to-be-deployed version against the version actually on the server to generate a diff script.  And it works for tables, views, functions, etc too.

You can also choose between a couple of different deployment methods, including generating a change script and applying it manually.